# How to use an S3 pre-signed POST url?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, express, amazon-s3, pre-signed-url

Actually, this is the first time that I'm using s3 for uploading files. I have heard about pre-signed urls But apparently, I can't set a limitation for file size so I found "pre-signed **post** urls" but it's a little bit wierd!! Surprisingly **I didn't find any example.** maybe it's not what I want.

I'm getting pre-signed post url from the server:

```
const { S3 } = require("aws-sdk");

const s3 = new S3({
  accessKeyId: accessKey,
  secretAccessKey: secretKey,
  endpoint: api,
  s3ForcePathStyle: true,
  signatureVersion: "v4",
});

app.post("/get-url", (req, res) => {
  const key = `user/${uuri.v4()}.png`;
  const params = {
    Bucket: "bucketName",
    Fields: {
      Key: key,
      ContentType: "image/png",
    },
  };

  s3.createPresignedPost(params, function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      console.error("Presigning post data encountered an error", err);
    } else {
      res.json({ url: data.url });
    }
  });
});
```

The weird thing is that the url that I get is not like a pre-signed url. it's just the endpoint followed by the bucket name. no query parameter. no option.

As you might guess, i can't use this url:

```
await axios.put(url, file, {
  headers: {
    "Content-Type": "image/png",
  },
});
```

I do not even know if I should use post or two requests.

I tried both, Nothing happens. Maybe the pre-signed **post** url is not like pre-signed url!

At least show me an example! I can't found any.

Comment: Have you got this to work? Is the field `key` or `Key`? The docs say `key` lower case, https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are on the right track, but you need to change the method you are invoking. The AWS S3 API docs of the [createPresignedPost()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property) that you are currently using states that:

> Get a pre-signed POST policy to support uploading to S3 directly from an HTML form.

Try change this method to either [getSignedUrl()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrl-property):

> Get a pre-signed URL for a given operation name.

```
const params = { Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key' };
s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params, function (err, url) {
  if (err) {
    console.error("Presigning post data encountered an error", err);
  } else {
    res.json({ url });
  }
});
```

or synchronously:

```
const params = { Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key' };
const url = s3.getSignedUrl('putObject', params)
res.json({ url });
```

Alternatively, use a promise by executing [getSignedUrlPromise()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#getSignedUrlPromise-property):

> Returns a 'thenable' promise that will be resolved with a pre-signed URL for a given operation name.

```
const params = { Bucket: 'bucket', Key: 'key' };
s3.getSignedUrlPromise('putObject', params)
  .then(url => {
     res.json({ url });
  }, err => { 
     console.error("Presigning post data encountered an error", err);
  });
```

Please also read the notes parts of the API documentation to make sure that you understand the limitations of each method.

Comment: `signedUrl` has disadvantages compared to `createPresignedPost`. The latter enables server-side validation by S3 server itself restricting Content Types and file size. We might not want a user to upload 4GB files.

Comment: @Gherman true, if used in the right context. Copied from the [createPresignedPost()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/S3.html#createPresignedPost-property) docs: `Get a pre-signed POST policy to support uploading to S3 directly from an HTML form.`. OP asked why the generated url "is not like a pre-signed url" and why it did not work with `axios.put()`, hence my answer.